# How to connect Google Drive on Android Studio for create a folder or file?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api, createfile

I want to connect to Google Drive API in Android studio and create a file and read that file but I can not connect even though I have an apiKey. If I am debugging, then the application closes after `GoogleApiClient.connect`. I have been researching various pages but some of them also take SHA1 fingerprints, is this necessary? What could I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the setup from the [Drive API Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started)

1. Install the [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html).
2. Download and configure the [Google Play services SDK](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup), which includes the Google Drive Android API.
3. Register your application. To do this, you need to register a project in the Google API Console and get a signing certificate for your app.
4. Add the [required settings](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/java-client#set_mime_types_in_the_app_manifest) to your application's manifest.
5. Add Drive services to your application. The easiest way to begin is by creating a file.

[Creating files](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file)

> You can create files in two ways with the Drive Android API: using the
>   CreateFileActivityBuilder class, or using the createFile() method of
>   the DriveFolder interface. The end result of either approach is the
>   same. However, for instances where the user is specifying the location
>   or title of the file, CreateFileActivityBuilder simplifies the process
>   by providing a premade user interface. To create files
>   programmatically or allow users to specify other metadata in a custom
>   UI activity, you must use the the createFile() method.

[Create a folder in the root folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/folders#create_a_folder_in_the_root_folder)

> To create a folder, call DriveFolder.createFolder for the root folder.
>   Pass the metadata containing the title and other attributes to set the
>   values for the folder.

[Create folder in Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder#creating_a_folder)

> In the Drive API, a folder is essentially a file — one identified by
>   the special folder MIME type application/vnd.google-apps.folder. You
>   can create a new folder by inserting a file with this MIME type and a
>   folder title. Do not include an extension when setting a folder title.